# Renaming field names when adding HTML field via ajax, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that the user can modify by adding certain fields, These fields can be of the same kind, and the code is injected using ajax by bringing in HTML.

I want to append an incremented number to the field name - so when the form is submitted I will have unique field names.

Here is a sample code (simplified).

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

        <script type="text/javascript" >
            rowNumber = 1;

            // INSERT FIELD(s)
            function addField( type ) {

                var url = type + '.html';
                var renamed = '';

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function( data ) {

                        console.log( data );

                        // I want to append an incrimented number to the field name
                        // I want my field names are taken from the incoming HTML but are incremented, so I don'thave conflicts when I submit
                        // So it will look like this <input type="text" name="field1" value="" /> or <input type="text" name="field2" value="" /> etc...
                        // I think I should do that here BEFORE I append it to the dom.
                        renamed = $( data ).attr( 'name', function() { return $( this ).attr( 'name' ) + rowNumber });

                        // append the html - with the unique name
                        $( '.segments' ).append( renamed );
                        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1;

                    },
                    error: function() {

                        console.log( 'error' );

                    }

                });

            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="content" >
            renaming field names when adding html field via ajax

            <form>
                <input type="button" value="+Add Field" onClick="addField( 'standard' );" />

                <div class="segments" >
                    <div class="row" >Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="" /><input type="text" name="lname" value="" /></div>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" />
            </form>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here is the "standard" html file that gets called via Ajax

```
<div class="row" >Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="" /><input type="text" name="lname" value="" /></div>
```

I am pretty sure I want to rename (or append) the incoming fields* in the success: before I append it to the DOM. But I am totally unclear how to do that.

*It should be noted that in some instances there will be multiple fields coming across in the HTML and I would want to append the same increment number to each.

Comment: why not work with arrays, like `fname[]`? No need to alter your names in js, and processing in the backend will probably be easier as well as you can just iterate over the array you receive.

Comment: @Pevara - I'll play with that idea - thanks, initially, due to how the actual form works, I need to know that each addition is numbered uniquely...if i read your suggestion correctly, the common names would be grouped in an array - and that wouldn't work for this project - but may work nicely for others. thx.

Answer (score 0):

set a counter and increase it each time:

JS:

```
i = 1;              

// INSERT FULL
function addField( type ) {         
  $( '.segments' ).append( '<div class="row" >Name:<input id="'+i+'" type="text" name="fname" value="" /><input type="text" name="lname" value="" /></div>' );      
  i = i + 1       
};
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/fb4fvkps/1/

Comment: ah yes - but how do i reference this as if it were coming from an ajax call??? That js fiddle is an 'example' - look at the question, those imputs will be coming in as html...

Comment: so just set the increment number when you make the ajax call and append it to the input name, whats the problem?

Comment: "data" is the variable returned from the ajax call... 
right now Im leaning towards: $(data).attr("name", function() { return $(this).attr("name") + i }); but im shooting in the dark, and wanted help.

Comment: i have updated the question with my current sticking point....plz ignore the fiddle -

Answer (score 0):

After much experimenting - This worked for me. If anyone spots any issues that may arise - please say something:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
            rowNumber = 1;

            // INSERT HTML 
            function addField( type ) {

                var url = type + '.html';
                var renamed = '';

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function( data ) {

                        // rename the form elements
                        var renamed = jQuery( data );
                            renamed.find( '[name]' ).attr( 'name', function() { return $( this ).attr( 'name' ) + rowNumber });

                        // append the html - with the unique name
                        $( '.segments' ).append( renamed );

                        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1;

                    },
                    error: function() {

                        console.log( 'error' );

                    }

                });

            };
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is passing the counter as data in ajax function then in server side prepare your html element and pass it to the client side like this :

```
 rowNumber = 1;  
 $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                dataType: 'html',
                data:{rowNumber:rowNumber},
                success: function( data ) {

                    console.log( data );




                    // append the html - with the unique name
                    $( '.segments' ).append( renamed );
                    rowNumber = rowNumber + 1;

                },
                error: function() {

                    console.log( 'error' );

                }

            });
```

Comment: yes farhadamjady that is simple for incrementing - my issue was how to reference the name attribute from the ajax data...adding the incrementor is then simple. thx

Comment: I can understand why do you want to rename the html element you can prepare the name attribute and other attributes in server side then pass them to client and just append it directly to html form; can you show the `data` content ?

Comment: the HTML is a template, not driven by server-side technology. generation of the UI was spec'd to be independent of server technology.

Comment: your right, what is the content of your `data` variable that comes from ajax call, this code: `renamed = $( data )` seems that `data` contains the string of html element.. @jpmyob